# MacOSX El Capitan: admin password only working from login screen

Tags: macos, password

Since a week or so, I have a very strange issue on my Mac... I can login from the login screen, but any further action that requires my password fails: from a terminal if I try to sudo, or from any system preferences pannel that prompts for my password. I cannot add "Show Input menu in login window" because this requires to enter my password... I have only one keyboard configured in System preferences so it is not even an issue of different keyboard layout as far as I can tell. And since my account is not bound to my appleid (and I need my password to do it) I am really stuck...

Is formatting the only option ?

Comment: Don't follow piece of advice which is not coming from someone who understood your problem.

Comment: To be clearer: **No, formatting isn't an option**, this is an advice from a bad genius :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `Textedit` and type there your password
to check which problem might be yours:

- typing errors,
- bad repeating tuning,
- num lock,
- keys problems,
- session configuration error.

If you think you have a typical problem with just the login window,
just configure your login so as to take advantage of your name
part of the login window to check how your keyboard and your software
are behaving.
Configure `System Preferences > Users & Groups` as follows:
[image: System Preferences > Users & Groups]

Within the `Name:` part of the login window, type all the characters
contained in your password and check for:

- bad repeating tuning,
- num lock,
- keys problems.

Comment: I tried all this, but always the same issue: if I log out and enter my password, it works. As soon as I am logged in, I cannot enter my password anymore.

Comment: By "all this" do you mean that you were able to type your password within `Textedit` with no problem?

Comment: Sorry I read what you put too quickly. My password contains a '!' and a '^' on a US keyboard (behind the 1 and 6) so the errors may come from here. But it is not a numlock issue since I tried with and without caps lock to be sure (and I also rebooted the mac many times). I am not sure what I can do....

Comment: Hallelujah ! Apparently the ^ character is not considered from the login screen, so I just removed it... Thanks !!

Comment: Do you  mean your password was `password^` and in fact the login screen was only reading `password`?

Comment: I bet a postcard that your keyboard isn't configured on the standard one when you are at your login window. Then the `^` might be configured as a dead key to introduce accented letters like `î`.•• return •• The receipe I just added to my answer would help to check this hypothesis: just type `^` in the name field.

Comment: I won the postcard :) !

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes keychain is broken. Try to [reset password](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202860)

Please don't forget to make backups.

Comment: Hello. As you are new, I would like to remind you that it is best to tell how to reset a password in the answer, not by linking to another page.

Comment: Unfortunately FileVault is off, I did not connect my AppleId, and there is no other admin account...